# Update status in django field - status CHOICES

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model django and I want to update my fields Status Choices:

my models.py

```
class Top(core.BaseModel):
    class Status(models.IntegerChoices):
        EMPTY = 0,'-----'
        SEND_CANCEL = 1, 'Send'
        CANCELLED = 2, 'Cancel'


  status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Status', choices=Status.choices, default='')
```

my views.py

```
class TopUpdateView(core.UpdateView):
    template_name = 'top/update_top.html'
    form_class = UpdateTopForm

@require_POST
def cancel_status(request, pk, status):
    top = get_object_or_404(Top, pk=pk, status=None, user=request.user)
    top.status= status.CANCELLED
    top.save(update_fields=['status'])
    return redirect('top:item-detail')
```

urls.py

```
path('top/<pk>/cancel/', views.cancel_status, name='cancel-status'),
```

template:

```
<button class="btn">
        <a href="{% url 'top:cancel-status' object.id %}">
          Cancel
      </button>
```

All what I want here it is update CHOICE field status from EMPTY on CANCELLED when I click on button. But it is does not work ((((
I know how to update and save simple field but do not unserstand the best way update Choices Field in view.Anybode please help me!

Comment: Can you provide more details of your `Top` model? Especially the field where you store the status?

Answer (score 2):

You need to submit a POST request, you can do that with:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'top:cancel-status' object.id %}">
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

In your view, you should use `Top.Status.EMPTY` to set the `status` field:

```
@require_POST
def cancel_status(request, pk, status):
    top = get_object_or_404(Top, pk=pk, status=None, user=request.user)
    top.status= Top.Status.CANCELLED
    top.save(update_fields=['status'])
    return redirect('top:item-detail')
```

Your `Top` model should of course have a `status` field with these choices:

```
class Top(core.BaseModel):
    class Status(models.IntegerChoices):
        EMPTY = 0,'-----'
        SEND_CANCEL = 1, 'Send'
        CANCELLED = 2, 'Cancel'
    
    status = status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        'Status',
        choices=Status.choices,
        default=Status.EMPTY
    )
```